# React/prefer-stateless-function vs class decorators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, eslint

So, I am setting up a brand new React project, and have updated all my deps to the latest versions.

This caused some eslint breakages in the project, so I'm going through and correcting these.

I seem to have come across conflicting rules. React/prefer-stateless-function tries to tell me to write my component as a pure function, but if I do that, I can no longer use decorators to connect my component to my Redux store.

How are people getting around this? The component in question is a "dumb" component (eg only props, no state), so honestly it should be written as a pure function, but then I lose the ability to connect it to my store via `@asyncConnect` and `@connect`.

**Class component with decorators:**

```
@connect(
  state => ({ // eslint-disable-line
    user: state.publicData.user.data,
    error: state.publicData.user.error,
    loading: state.publicData.user.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey })
export default class UserProfile extends Component {
  ...stuff
}
```

**Pure function component:**

```
// How can I use decorators?
export default function UserProfile(props) {
  ...stuff
}
```

**Case of two decorators combined:**

```
@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({ params, store: { dispatch, getState } }) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadUser(params.userID))
    }
  },
}])
@connect(
  state => ({ // eslint-disable-line
    user: state.publicData.user.data,
    error: state.publicData.user.error,
    loading: state.publicData.user.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey })
export default class UserProfile extends Component {
  ...stuff
}
```

Comment: http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-react-createclass-es6-classes-or-stateless-functional-components/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux doesn't need decorators to work, `connect` is really just a function. You can use it like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(props => <div />)
```

Comment: Ah, of course. And in the case of two combined decorators (I updated my post), you would just call one inside the other?

Comment: Yes, the decorators are just doing this in the background for you. When using them as normal functions, you need to understand what the function actually does (and what it returns). I think the same should be true when using decorators, otherwise it's too magic imo.

Comment: In this case I cannot figure out whether asyncConnect or regular connect is primary, or how to structure the function chain.

Comment: I haven't used asyncConnect, but looking at it quickly makes me wonder if you really need to use both connect and asyncConnect? Doesn't asyncConnect use Redux's connect in the background?

Comment: I believe so, need to do some more reading. This came directly out of a boilerplate I used to get started.